# Converting constructor of templated non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

When throwing `T::v` of type `int` into `t<>`, I would expect `N` to be created by use of `n`'s converting constructor. However, for some reason GCC seems to look for member `i` in `c<int, 3>::v`. What does the C++20 standard say about this type of construction or deduction for non-type template parameters?

```
#include <concepts>

template<auto...>
struct n {
    constexpr n(int x): i{x} {}
    int i;
};
template<typename T, T V>
struct c { static constexpr T v = V; };

template<n N>
using t = c<decltype(N.i), N.i>;

// clang ok, gcc nope, msvc ok
static_assert([]<typename T = t<3>>
    { return std::same_as<T, t<T::v>>; }());
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/qd73bbe8d)

---

The error message from GCC:

```
<source>: In instantiation of '<lambda()> [with T = c<int, 3>]':
<source>:15:41:   required from here
<source>:15:19: error: request for member 'i' in 'c<int, 3>::v', which is of
non-class type 'const int'
   15 |     { return std::same_as<T, t<T::v>>; }());
      |              ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Maybe a simpler example: https://godbolt.org/z/hz178nroz (Seems like a problem when "inlining" a type alias, the type isn't adjusted properly from `int` -> `n`. I would think that this is a GCC bug)

Comment: How the type of n is deduced? Can't catch how the template parms <auto...> should be deduced here...

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference in template context if using a `constexpr int` or an `int` literal normally, so I'd agree on the GCC bug with @Artyer. Maybe write a bug report?

Comment: @Klaus If that's the problem, however, then `t<3>` shouldn't work either. Solution should be pretty simple, though: As it's `auto...`, not `auto` then the template parameter set should be empty, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Klaus It's CTAD deduced as an empty pack. But the problem still happens if you remove it (make `n` not a template)

Comment: how is the compiler supposed to deduce template parameters for type `n` from `3`? `n::n` is independent of template parameters and there's no CTAD guide either.

Comment: Naming convention is terribly irreadable. Normally types are capitalized and values are lower case. And single character IDs are awful too.

Comment: @Red.Wave The implicitly-generated deduction guide from the constructor in `n`'s primary template is used for CTAD (deducing the pack as empty).

Comment: Seems like a GCC bug to me.

Comment: @Artyer Thanks for providing a more simplified version. For now, I'll leave it as it is as others have already provided an answer to this question.

Comment: @Red.Wave I do not agree with your notion. In my experience, it's very common to see the names of types in lower case and the names of NTTPs in upper case (e.g.: `std::array`). And the use of single-letter identifiers falls in line with lots of examples provided in the C++ standard that are designed to demonstrate a specific language mechanic.

Comment: @303 you've done all sorts of evil to make the snippet unreadable. The outcome of all those reasoning of yours is something that really gives a headache to everyone. Don't skip all the recommendations at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comments, your understanding is correct and this is definitely a GCC bug.  Strictly, the answer to the question is that C++20 says unfortunately little about how the template parameter object is initialized.  A [defect report](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2023/p2308r1.html) has just been approved; until that link works the [previous version](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2023/p2308r0.html) is available.